# How do I decide what testing framework to use?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, web-applications, frameworks

The situation is this.

I'm a junior developer for a small government IT project. We don't have anything of continuous integration or a automated testing framework. But the idea is to be developing this kind of thing/improving our developing environment.

The product is a data processing algorithm that then displays information to the end user via a webapp.

So coming up is a bunch of work modifying the webapp javascript. As such we want to implement a unit testing for the javascript.

I've looked at this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd) which outlines several different unit testing frameworks for javascript.

The question is - how do I decide between which framework to start using?

- What is a list of criteria for choosing a testing framework?
- Is it practical to try them all out?
- Spend a lot of time reading forums/etc about how they're used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***What is a list of criteria for choosing a testing framework?***

**1) Syntax**

As you investigate different test frameworks you will notice that syntax is a differentiating factor across all of them.  This is really going to depend on what makes you feel comfortable.

For example, [qUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) is more of a declarative test framework.  Its API consists of functions called test, equals, strictEqual, deepEqual, etc.

Another test framework, [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/), is more like rspec in that it reads in a more sentence like structure.  Its API consists of functions called describe, it, assert.equal, etc.

My personal preference is a qunit like structure.

**2) Features - Stubs, Spies, Fake server, Fake clock, etc**

When you start testing in Javascript you will quickly find yourself in situations where you need your test framework to help you test certain use cases.  For example:

Spies - This will help you detect whether your code called a function when it should have

Stubs - Very similar to a spy except it contains predefined behavior (Example: When the stub is called, return foo)

Fake Server - If your code issues AJAX calls and you want to fake the response of the AJAX call, a Fake Server will help you more easily test.

Fake Clock - If your code reacts differently based on the date or time, then a fake clock will help you control exactly what time it is while your test runs.

My recommendation for a Javascript Framework that supports all the features above is [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/).  Because I like a qunit like syntax and framework, I use qunit AND Sinon.JS.  qunit handles my assertions and runs my tests.  Sinon.JS gives me the ability to stub, spy, run a fake server, and fake the clock.

**3) Community Support**

Is your test framework supported by the community?  For example, grunt (a build environment tool) supports running qunit in a headless PhantomJS server: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit .  This makes it easy to write tests and have them be *automatically* run everytime I save the test file.

***Is it practical to try them all out?***
No it is not practical. Instead investigate each framework's website and pick one that you feel comfortable with and one that will also support you while your write tests.

***Spend a lot of time reading forums/etc about how they're used?***
Grab a book on the framework you choose and skim through it as you need it.